# How to interactivelly pass a `listp arg` to `yank`

Tags: interactive, yank, prefix-argument

Is it possible to *interactively* pass an argument that matches `listp` to the function `yank` so that `current-kill` receives an argument of `0`?  If so, how please can that be achieved?

**Background**:

I am using `multiple-cursors` ( https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el ) and frequently find the need to block and copy information from another Emacs buffer while `multiple-cursors` remains active.  Then, I switch back to the buffer where `multiple-cursors` is active, and I try to paste the same information to every cursor.  Unless `current-kill` (within the `yank` function) receives an argument of `0`, the first cursor receives the paste and then an error message is generated by `current-kill` -- i.e., `The kill-ring is empty.`  The error message is caused due to the failure of passing a `listp arg` to `yank` when interactively using same -- i.e., from a kebboard shortcut.  The default argument within `yank` (when no argument is given) is `(1- arg)` -- and that is what causes the error message.  If `yank` had been called with a `listp arg`, then `current-kill` would have received a `0` and everything would have worked as expected.

I do not understand when the default of `(1- arg)` would be helpful, but changing that to `0` (i.e., hacking `yank`) avoids the error message and achieves the desired effect.  If possible, I would prefer to avoid hacking `yank`.

Although not essential to this question, it sure would be nice to know an example where `(1- arg)` could be useful.

---

P.S.

The issue is now resolved, but I wanted to add the explanation of `(1- arg)` within the function `yank`.  `(1- arg)` is the nth entry in the kill-ring, which can be accessed when the `arg` is not a `list` or `-`.  There is an apparent bug in the `yank` function in the October 1, 2014 build of Emacs Trunk (which may be present in other versions) -- i.e., at the outset of `yank`, there should be `(unless arg (setq arg 1))` [*which is missing*].  I'll make a note on my todo-list to check a current version of Emacs Trunk and then file a bug-report if it is missing in the latest build also.

With respect to copying and pasting the same entry at multiple active cursors, additional code is needed when copying from within Emacs versus copying from an external program.  The author of multiple-cursors has already included a revision of `current-kill` through an `advice` for the external kill-ring -- similar code is needed for copying from within Emacs -- however, that is beyond the scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd> to to interactively pass a `listp arg` to `yank`.

`yank` uses `(interactive "P")` which means the prefix argument is passed in **raw** form.

When a prefix arg is supplied via one or more <kbd>C-u</kbd> presses (only), the raw form of the argument is a list: `(4)` or `(16)` or `(64)`, etc...

(And similarly for the `-` argument, which is also tested for explicitly in this function.)

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Hence the varied behaviour described by the function's docstring:

```
With just C-u as argument, put point at beginning, and mark at end.
With argument N, reinsert the Nth most recent kill.
```